# Vollständige Liste gemischt trennbarer und nichttrennbarer Verben gesucht

Tags: conjugation

Gesucht wird eine möglichst vollständige Liste von allen Verben, die nur im Perfekt trennbar sind, wie:

> er schlafwandelt, er ist schlaf*ge*wandelt
>
> er notlandet, er ist not*ge*landet

Comment: Ich besitze nicht eine solche Liste. Was mir aber spontan einfällt als eine eventuelle generelle Regel: Wenn man 'in/im' verwenden kann, um das Verb in Verb + 'in/im' + Nomen zerlegen zu können. Bezogen auf deine Beispiele: er wandelt im Schlaf. er ist im Schlaf gewandelt. er landet in Not. er ist in Not gelandet. Wobei ich eine Ergänzung anführen würde. Beides sind in gewisserweise Zustände. Doch die Benutzung dieser unterscheidet sich. Denn das zweite Verb beinhaltet den Grund für die Aktion (also landen). Weshalb auch möglich wäre einen kausalen Ansatz zu verwenden. (Teil 1)

Comment: er landet aufgrund von Not. er ist aufgrund von Not gelandet. Doch diese Verwendung ist recht altertümlich. Generell ist es wohl modern solche Verben zusammen zu schreiben (zusammenzuschreiben). Rein eine Beobachtung. Man könnte zu diesem "Phänomen" noch weiter philosophieren. (Teil 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In der Forschung sind diese Verben als "verbale Pseudokomposita" bekannt. Beim Googeln bin ich auf folgende Bachelorarbeit gestoßen, die das Thema behandelt: Emely Henderiks (2017), *Verbale Pseudokomposita im Vergleich mit den Partikelverben*, [Link](https://theses.ubn.ru.nl/handle/123456789/4802).

Dort wird zwischen syntaktischer und morphologischer Trennbarkeit unterschieden:

> abzufahren, abgefahren (morphologisch trennbar)
>   fährt ab (syntaktisch trennbar)

Die Frage suggeriert, daß *schlafwandeln* und *notlanden* morphologisch trennbar und syntaktisch untrennbar seien. In Wahrheit existiert große Unsicherheit, was die Trennbarkeit solcher Verben angeht, wie die Korpusbelege auf den Seiten 32-63 zeigen: *saugt Staub* neben *staubsaugt*, *haushaltet* neben *hält haus* (allerdings immer ungetrennt *schlafwandelt*); *gestaubsaugt* neben *staubgesaugt*, *hausgehalten* neben *gehaushaltet*.

Mein Eindruck ist, daß Sprecher der Entscheidung darüber, ob ein solches Verb syntaktisch trennbar ist oder nicht, gerne dadurch aus dem Weg gehen, daß sie die Voranstellung meiden, das Verb also entweder mit einem Modalverb verbinden oder in einem Verbletztsatz verwenden.

Auf S. 32 der genannten Arbeit findet sich folgende Liste verbaler Pseudokomposita:

> bauchlanden, bauchreden, bausparen, bergsteigen, brandschatzen, bruchrechnen, brustschwimmen, dienstverpflichten, generalüberholen, handhaben, haushalten, hohnlachen, hohnlachen, kettenrauchen, kopfzurechnen, kunststopfen, lobhudeln, lobpreisen, lobsingen, lustwandeln, mutmassen, nachtwandeln, nasführen, notlanden, notschlachten, nottaufen, notwassern, prämiensparen, preiskegeln, probefilmen, probelaufen, rückenschwimmen, sachlaufen, sackhüpfen, schlafwandeln, schutzimpfen, schweifwedeln, seilspringen, seiltanzen, sonnenbaden, staubsaugen, strafexerzieren, strafversetzen, wetterleuchten, wettlaufen, wettrennen, wettstreiten, willfahren

Answer (score -2):

ich bin ziemlich sicher, daß es keine vollständige Liste gibt, weil noch neue Verben in dieser Gruppe erzeugt werden können. Ich würde mich an folgendem orientieren:

Wenn die Betonung auf dem Präfix liegt und dieses selbständig stehen kann, dann wird getrennt, sonst nicht. Beispiele: a) **Über**führen (transfer): Er hat (etwas oder jemanden) übergeführt. b) über**fÜhren** (convict): Er hat (jemanden) überführt. c) antworten: Er hat geantwortet. Die Sache wird noch erschwert, weil manche Leute (z.B. ich) in der Betonung schlampig sind und über**fÜhren** sagen, obwohl sie **Über**führen meinen

Comment: Die Antwort ist leider komplett an der Frage vorbei. Ich frage nicht nach Präfixen, die bedeutungsunterscheidend trennbar oder untrennbar sind (über-, unter-, durch-, um-), sondern nach Präfixen, die NUR im Perfekt trennbar sind.

Comment: Der Ton dürfte ruhig etwas freundlicher sein. Ich wollte nur helfen... Viel Glück noch beim Einsammeln weiterer Antworten!

Comment: Mein Ton war nicht unfreundlich. Ich glaube, das hast du beim Lesen reininterpretiert.

Answer (score -2):

Schau mal [hier](http://www.verblisten.de/listen/verben/erstteil/trennbar/zusammengesetzt/vollstaendig.html).

"Berücksichtigt werden nur Verben, deren Präfix bzw. deren Vorsilbe betont und trennbar ist."

Müsste also das sein, was du suchst.

Comment: Nein, das ist nicht das was er sucht: Erstes Verb hinter deinem Link: "abändern": er ändert ab / er hat abgeändert. -> wurde im Präsens getrennt, aber er sucht Verben, die im Präsens nicht getrennt werden, wie "er schlafwandelt."